# Data is failing to pass over

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Inside of my tableview.swift I have the users profiles loaded into cells. When the user selects one of these cells they are then redirected to mainProfile.swift where they can see the selected user profile. After reading several posts I have this code set up inside of tableview.swift, but it still doesn't pass the data that is captured from tableview's cell into mainProfile

```
var mainProfile: mainProfile?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user1 = self.users[indexPath.row]
    mainProfile?.user2 = user1
    print(mainProfile?.user2 as Any)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainProfile", sender: self)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mainProfile" {
        let viewControllerAccept = segue.destination as! mainProfile
        let user2 = sender as Any?
        viewControllerAccept.user2 = user2 as! User?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simplify `didSelectRowAt` to just perform the segue:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainProfile", sender: self)    
}
```

(Or remove this method entirely, and just add the segue directly to the cell prototype in the storyboard.)

Then, change `prepare(segue:)` to use `indexPathForSelectedRow` to know which row was selected:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mainProfile" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let viewController = segue.destination as! MainProfileViewController
        viewController.user2 = users[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I changed the name of your destination view controller's class because per Cocoa naming conventions, classes should always start with uppercase letter. Obviously, use whatever class name is appropriate in your case.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you enough! This solution worked perfectly, thank you again